# Validate Log in

Tags: php, android, html, ajax, cordova

I have this problem in my phonegap application. It seems like If-else method is not functioning here.

This is my code:

```
function onSuccess(position){
  $("#Login").click(function(evt){


  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var d = new Date();
  var date = d.getUTCDate();
  var hour = d.getUTCHours()+8;
  var minutes = d.getUTCMinutes();
  var secs = d.getUTCSeconds();
  var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
  var mon = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getUTCDay();
  var time = year + "-" + mon + "-" + date + " " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + secs;   
  var sendData = {"username": username, "password" : password, "time" : time};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://192.168.254.107/webs/main/ajax/validateLogin.php",
    data: sendData,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#info").html(data);
        var ReturnMessage = data; // I also tried data.message here but it gives me "undefined"


        if (ReturnMessage != "" && ReturnMessage != "Invalid Login!") {
            alert(ReturnMessage);
            localStorage.setItem("message", ReturnMessage);
            document.location.href = "trackme.html";

        } else {
            alert(ReturnMessage);
        }

    }

});

  });
```

}

What ever value of ReturnMessage is, it always do the method of if condition. If I got "Log in Succesful!" message from my php file it redirects to trackme.html, if I got "Invalid Login!", it also redirects to trackme.html which means If-else condition is not functioning. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please cross check the data you are getting. There must be some extra space of white space. Try trimming the data: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1786-javascript-trim-function

Answer (score 0):

HI the return value of ajax request was a OBJECT try to use JSON.stringify(ReturnMessage) and check

Comment: hi, where am I going to place JSON.stringify(ReturnMessage)? do I need to replace code there or something? thank you.